# jBPM not allows to move and customize the positon of symbol label

Tags: label, jbpm

I'm using the jBPM Server distribution, exactly the jBPM 7.74.1.Final server (single zip) distribution and I have install it in my local machine.

When I design a Business Process diagram, jBPM automatically fix the label position for each symbol. In some cases, especially in diagrams with many symbols, in gateways or flow sequences, the labels appear on top of other symbols or very misplaced, making the reading and interpretation of the diagram difficult.
Does anyone know if there is a way to select each label and move it to a specific position to make the diagram easier to read and interpret?

[Diagram example with problems remarked in red and my comments to explain them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr7SX.png)

Comment: Can you share screenshot of bpmn diagram so that we will have better understanding about the issue

Comment: Hi. I have added a diagram example with problems remarked in red and comments to explain them. Regards